# Upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 using the desktop image

Tags: upgrade, apt, 12.10

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 desktop iso using bittorrent (because it's faster) [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/).

This time I'm stuck because there isn't an alternate install with a `cdromupgrade` script  and I'm not really sure how to use `apt-cdrom` either.

Is there any way to use this image to upgrade my current installation without re-downloading everything ?

Comment: OP filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1068657

Answer (score 0):

The release notes clearly indicate that you should not use CDs, but instead use the online upgrade method.

```
$ upgrade-manager
```

Or

```
$ do-release-upgrade
```

Make sure that you change sources to prefer normal (non-lts) releases, or modify this file

```
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: The [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading) tell to use the standard upgrade manager but I didn't find where it says _not_ to use the desktop image which clearly offers the option.